# How can I change background color for child windows in Qt MDI project?

Tags: qt, qtgui

How can I change background color for child windows in Qt MDI project?

[image: Qt-MDI - background color]

Comment: if you want changed to QMdiArea's background color, then use the setBackground() with QBrush. eg. yourMdiArea->setBackground(Qt::yellow);

Answer (score 1):

If mdiSubWindow is a pointer to your child window use code like

```
mdiSubWindow->setStyleSheet("background-color:<color you like>;");
```

can be a (well known) name (e.g. white) or a numeric value
(e.g. #ff00dc).